# How to remove indentation of list items

Tags: html, css, jsp, listitem

I have padding-left set to zero and margin-left set to zero and yet my list items are still being indented, whereas I want them to align with the h2 element. My code and screenshot of problem:

My login.jsp:

```
<!-- Welcome page options -->
    <div class="homepageNavButtons">
        <h2 id="loginLabel" class="homepageOptionsText">Welcome to the SGA web application. Choose
            an option:</h2>
        <ul class="homepageNavButtonsList">
            <li><a class="loginOptions"
                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/menu" tabindex="1">
                    Click here to login</a></li>
            <li><a class="registerOptions"
                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" tabindex="2">Click
                    here to register </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
.homepageNavButtons {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    margin: auto;
}

.homepageNavButtonsList ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.homepageNavButtonsList li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.loginOptions {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.registerOptions {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not selecting the `ul` to remove all its styles. Try this:

```
ul.homepageNavButtonsList {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

You had `.homepageNavButtonsList ul` with `padding-left: none` and of course you didn't have any `ul` inside the `.homepageNavButtonsList`

Comment: @smoggers Checking the checkmark is how you mark as an accepted answer, but you have to wait 15 minutes from asking your question to be able to do it.